# animating a hero with a double key press as3 Flash Pro CS6

Tags: actionscript-3, key

Im creating a space shooter. Im trying to figure out how I can code/ run my movie clip  (muzzle flash) when spacebar and a directional key are pressed at the same time.

This was my AS2 code using keyframes within Flash itself:

```
if(Key.isDown(Key.SPACE)){
    this.gotoAndStop("20");
} else {
    this.gotoAndStop("idle");
}

if(Key.isDown(Key.RIGHT)){
    this._x += 5;
    this.gotoAndStop("6");
}

if(Key.isDown(Key.SPACE)){
    this.gotoAndStop("20");
}

if(Key.isDown(Key.LEFT)){
    this._x -= 5;
    this.gotoAndStop("6");
}

and so on...
```

Comment: This was  my AS2 code using keyframes  within Flash itself:   if(Key.isDown(Key.SPACE)){
    
    this.gotoAndStop("20");
    }
 else {
this.gotoAndStop("idle");
   }
 
 if(Key.isDown(Key.RIGHT)){
    this._x += 5;
    this.gotoAndStop("6");
    }
 
    if(Key.isDown(Key.SPACE)){
    
    this.gotoAndStop("20");
    }
    if(Key.isDown(Key.LEFT)){
    this._x -= 5;
    this.gotoAndStop("6");
    }

  and so on...

Comment: Did you try using `&&` operator to link two condtions? Something like `if (event.keyCode == 40 && event.keyCode == 45) { Do something; }` replace the 40 & 45 with correct key codes for left Arrow and Space key. Also double-check the correct AS3 syntax (you did not show AS3 code we can help to fix)...

Comment: @VC.One I surmise they have yet to learn about eventlisteners.

Comment: @NealDavis I can't even be sure if Asker is really making an AS3 code project or they just like to call AS2 as AS3...

Comment: @VC.One mmm. I interpret it as they have a working as2 project they are converting to AS3.

Answer (score 1):

If this was me, I would do something like this in AS3:

```
stop();

var velocity: Vector3D = new Vector3D(0,0,0);
var shooting: Boolean = false;
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, function(evt: KeyboardEvent){
    // have we moved on the X axis?
    velocity.x = evt.keyCode == 37 ? -1: evt.keyCode == 39 ? 1: velocity.x;
    // have we moved on the Y axis?
    velocity.y = evt.keyCode == 40 ? -1: evt.keyCode == 38 ? 1: velocity.y;
    // Have we shot?
    shooting = evt.keyCode == 32 ? true : shooting;
});

stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, function(evt: KeyboardEvent){
    // Have we finished moving on the X axis?
    velocity.x = evt.keyCode == 37 || 39 ? 0 : velocity.x;
    // Have we finished moving on the Y axis?
    velocity.y = evt.keyCode == 40 || 38 ? 0 : velocity.y;
    // have we finished shooting?
    shooting = evt.keyCode == 32 ? false : shooting;
});

stage.addEventListener(Event.EXIT_FRAME, function(evt: Event){
    // evaluate velocity and shooting and jump to the required keyframes.
    trace(velocity, shooting);
});
```

The key to it is assessing which key was pressed in the two `Keyboard event listeners` and then at the end of the frame, then update the movieclip according to all of the data that has been gathered. I think this is important because you know that when the spaceship finally moves, it will definitely be in the most up to date state.

I also use a [`Vector3D`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/geom/Vector3D.html) to store the velocity of the spaceship as it has numerous helpful properties for calculating movement of objects such as `Vector3D.scaleBy()` for applying speed to the spacecraft and `Vector3D.distance()` for calculating the distance between the spaceship and an enemy which might be used for weapon accuracy or damage in relation to distance.

Comment: @CaseyY Glad I could help - if this ended up solving your solution, please accept it as the correct answer so people will know it worked well in the future :)